# How to make map object (eg: circle) clickable in android google maps v2?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Google recently introduced the circle as a map object in V2 and can easily be drawn:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/shapes#circles

Does anyone know how to make this clickable, so that I can open an info window etc... ?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:**

You should probably use `GoogleMap::setOnCircleClickListener`.

**Old answer:**

For Circles it should be easy: use OnMapClickListener and this code:

```
void onMapClick(LatLng position) {

    LatLng center = circle.getCenter();
    double radius = circle.getRadius();
    float[] distance = new float[1];
    Location.distanceBetween(position.latitude, position.longitude, center.latitude, center.longitude, distance);
    boolean clicked = distance[0] < radius;

}
```

You can of course iterate over circles if you have more of them.

For others you have to code checking yourself. The algorithm for Polygon is not hard to find online.

Comment: alright, i will try it out tonight. and yes, I will be iterating over multiple circles.

Comment: @HarshadMadaye You will likely not see the map underneath them all. Anyway, you may check my updated answer.

Comment: @MaciejGórski i solved my problem using mMap.setOnCircleClickListener, i found it in google docs, i'm making my circles 50% transperent , so map is also visible. thanks for response bro.

Answer (score 7):

As of June 2016, Google has introduced clickable property of CircleOptions.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CircleOptions#public-constructor-summary

You can use Circle.setClickable(boolean) method as well and listen to OnCircleClickListener event.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle.html#public-methods

Answer (score 2):

It's very straight forward - mMap.setOnCircleClickListener(this);